# Laravel 9 Eloquent Model - Reserved Column Names in Model

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-9

I've got a postgres database with a table that has a column called 'attributes'.

The attributes column is of jsonb type, so I am using an Eloquent cast:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'attributes' => AsArrayObject::class,
];
```

This appears to be causing an issue as 'attributes' is already an Eloquent Model property and there doesn't appear to be any provision for aliasing column names.

So the line:

```php
$this->attributes['a_property_of_the_attributes_jsonb_field'] = 'hello word!';
```

appears to be accessing the internal Eloquent Model attributes property - and not the 'attributes' field in my database table resulting in the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "a_property_of_the_attributes_jsonb_field" of relation "mytable" does not exist
LINE 1: update "mytable" set "a_property_of_the_attributes_jsonb_field" = $1 where "mypk" = ...
```

I can't rename the column as other non PHP projects are using the DB.

How can I access my 'attributes' field in the Model as an ArrayObject?

Comment: Could you try reaching the "attributes" field in your model like this: `$this->attributes['attributes']`

Comment: If do that then I get the following error

```PHP
Cannot access offset of type string on string {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Cannot access offset of type string on string at /workspace/myapp/laravel/app/Models/mymodel.php:123)
```
I suspect Eloquent is not casting the jsonb field as an array in the $casts list:

```PHP
protected $casts = [
    'attributes' => AsArrayObject::class,
];
```

Comment: Yes, I also think that's the case since we get a string but no offset.

Answer (score 0):

The simple workaround is to use the ArrayObject accessor methods:

```
$this['attributes'] = ['x' => 'y'];
$stuff = $this['attributes'];
```

Note: The 'attributes' cast still need to be defined in order to access the underlying jsonb field as an array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'attributes' => AsArrayObject::class
];
```